# R: How to download single file from specific branch of private GitHub repo?

Tags: r, github, github-api

How to download **single file** from **specific branch** of GitHub **private** repo **using R**?

It can be easily done for default branch, e.g.:

```
require(httr)

github_path = "https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/contents/{path_to}/{file}"
github_pat = Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT"))

req <- content(GET(github_path,
                   add_headers(Authorization = paste("token", github_pat))), as = "parsed")

tmp <- tempfile()
r1 <- GET(req$download_url, write_disk(tmp))
```

...but I can't figure out how to do that for specific branch.
Tried to include branch name in `github_path` but it didn't work (`Error in handle_url(handle, url, ...)`).

Since it is easy with classic `curl`, e.g.:

```
curl -s -O https://{PAT}@raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{path_to}/{file}
```

...I tried to do it like:

```
tmp <- tempfile()
curl::curl_download("https://{PAT}@raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{path_to}/{file}", tmp)
```

But it didn't work as well.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl in R like this to include the auth header and the path to the desired file:

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle(verbose = TRUE)
handle_setheaders(h,
  "Authorization" = "token ghp_XXXXXXX"
)
con <- curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/branch/path/file.R", handle = h)
readLines(con)
```